# Override file in parent theme

Tags: child-theme, parent-theme

Presumably a common question, but I'm having some difficulty as it's my first time editing WordPress themes.

I'm trying to create child theme based on Zincious. This is all fine for CSS, but when it comes to editing HTML, it doesn't work. I have the same file name and path as the original. Any idea what could be going wrong? All I'm trying to do for now is comment out / delete a div.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Exactly what file are you trying to replace?

Comment: One file is library.php within the includes folder.

Comment: Is library.php a template? Or just a file of functions? You can only override templates in the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).  I'm not familiar with that theme so I can't know.

Comment: See this link it might be useful to you.This shows how to override the files in parent themes folder
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/overriding-parent-theme-sub-files-with-a-child-theme-how

Answer (score 1):

if it the functions file, the child theme is loaded in conjunction with it's parent, the child being loaded first.

If its the index.php file, you need to make sure your WordPress version greater than or equal to 3.0.  Otherwise, your index.php file won't overwrite.

A lot of reworking of themes has happened, so make sure you check out the documentation on themes and more specifically child theme overrides.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/

Basically, to overwrite another file, simply make sure it has the same name.  If your trying to overwrite a theme specific (ie. not WordPress default theme file) file, it won't work.  You'll have to overwrite at he WordPress specific theme name and go from there.

For example, if you are trying to override `page.php`, just place a `page.php` file in your child theme directory.

If `page.php` includes or requires some specific file in some parent theme sub-directory, you'll have to override `page.php` and change the include location.